# Accessing members of a struct via an array of pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

The second if statement in main does not print out. If I put just one of the if statements they do execute, but for some reason putting them after each other causes the second if statement to not print anything. Can anyone explain why this happens?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct entry {
    int value;        
    char *key;
    int type;
} entry;

entry* array[5];

void init_arr(){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        array[i] = NULL;
    }

    entry new;
    new.value = 2;
    new.key = NULL;
    new.type = 5;
    array[3]= &new;
        
}

int main(){
    init_arr();

    if(array[3]->value == 2){
        printf("ok\n");
    }

    if(array[3]->key == NULL){
        printf("ok 2\n");
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: I've just tried your code but it prints `ok 2`

Comment: I think what you meant to write was `entry array[5];` (an array of `entry` structs) rather than `entry* array[5];` (an array of `entry` pointers)... that would have made the whole thing much easier... but if you want pointers, than you really don't want to to initialize the same pointer with stack memory (`array[3]= &new`)

Comment: that's weird, when i run it in visual studio code it only prints the first if statement

Comment: thanks @Myst , but i did want an array of entry pointers, i simplified this code but in my implementation i do indeed need an array of entry pointers. i just filled something random in array[3] to show that when i access different members of the same struct the second if statement doesnt execute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new` is an automatic variable. It only exists while `init_arr()` is executing. As soon as you leave that function, the memory previously used for `new` may be used for some other thing, so both `array[3]->key` and `array[3]->value` are actually not defined.

If you get "right" values for `array[3]->value` is just because there is still a chance that memory used for `new` hasn't been already recycled by the time if first `if` is evaluated, but it has surely changed by the time the second `if` is evaluated.

If you need the memory used by `new` to be valid even after the function has exited, declare it `static`.

```
void init_arr()
{
    static entry new;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        array[i] = NULL;

    new.value = 2;
    new.key = NULL;
    new.type = 5;
    array[3]= &new;
}
```

Or allocate memory for it:

```
void init_arr()
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        array[i] = NULL;

    array[3] = malloc(sizeof *array);     
    array[3].value = 2;
    array[3].key = NULL;
    array[3].type = 5;
}
```